# NoneType object is not iterable - shuffle list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I used main module and module alti in below. I want shuffled list in module alti but i get "'NoneType' object is not iterable" error. How can I fix this error?

```
#main module
import alti
a=[1,2,3,4]
alti.shuffle_list(*a)


#module alti
import random
def shuffle_list(*args):
  args=list(args)
  new_list=random.shuffle(args)
  print(new_list)
```

Comment: `random.shuffle()` doesn't return a new list, it modifies the original list in place.

Comment: [random.shuffle()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) shuffles the list in place, it doesn't return a list, so `new_list` is None for you

Comment: Although that shouldn't produce this error. It should just print `None`. Show the full traceback of the error.

Comment: Right my code produce this error for i wrote new_list=list(random.shuffle(args)) otherwise produce None.

Comment: I fix my code: **main module** :
`import alti a=[1,2,3,4]
alti.shuffle_list(a)`  
**module alti**  `import random  
   def shuffle_list(liste=[]):
       random.shuffle(liste)
       print(liste)`